# npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed: express@latest

Tags: express, methods, npm, installation

Of the several 405 related Questions posted here, none apply to my issue.

**Here is the command I issued from Windows 7 on my Desktop PC:**

```
npm install express
```

**Here is the Error message:**

```
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed: express@latest
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\mr9832\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-21T20_36_09_581Z-debug.log
```

**Here is the verbose Error Log mentioned above**

C:\Users\mr9832\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-21T20_36_09_581Z-debug.log

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is probably a network problem. You have a firewall issue, or your ISP is doing something dumb. Try from a completely different network. Or try from a new Windows 7 account in case it is some setting in your .npmrc file. Make sure your npm registry setting is default and has a trailing slash. Basically, work from the known to the unknown. This is an environmental problem that we will not be able to solve for you.

Answer (score 11):

This answer is probably a little bit too late, but I had the same problem. I fixed it by putting following settings in the npm config (located in `%USERDATA%/.npmrc`):

```
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

It requests the packages over plain `http` instead of the secure `https`.

Comment: Is there a need to edit the file as an admin for window users

Comment: I had to use `%userprofile%` instead of `%userdata%`.

Comment: @Charles - I edited the file as myself, a non-admin.

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

Or you may edit the **~/.npmrc** file:

```
proxy=http://username:password@host:port
https-proxy=http://username:password@host:port
https_proxy=http://username:password@host:port
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out the `proxy` and/or `https-proxy` config pointed to the wrong proxy server.

The following commands set the proxy to the correct address:

```sh
npm config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128
npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with pnpm, so I fixed it using this command:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably other answer will work but I tired below and its working like a charm

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```