# why does react native form installation give an error?

Tags: npm-install

I tried to install react-native-dynamic-form. Now npm is also not working. 
  Why isn't it?

```
PS D:\reactNative> npm install -g react-native-cli
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react- 
native-dynamic-form/react-native-dynamic-form/react-native-cli

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04- 
25T11_13_54_616Z-debug.log
```

giving error, 405?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed: express@latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915738/npm-err-405-method-not-allowed-expresslatest)

Answer (score 0):

Many problems related with npm have some common solutions.

Here is 2 of them:

1. Try to update npm with command `npm update` or just `npm install` - (this one just install's the latest version so this 2 commands are common)
2. Try to clean Your cache with `npm cache clean`

Good luck :)