# npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed: ionic cli

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2, node-modules, npm-install

I am getting this error when I run

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

I tried to refer other related questions but I can't find the solution.

**Error message**
[image]

I am using Node v14.15.4 and npm 6.14.10. I have also tried this solution [npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed: express@latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915738/npm-err-405-method-not-allowed-expresslatest)

What should I do to reolve this error

Comment: You tried that solution from the link? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540985/998096) because in the error it stills relates to "http*s*//registry.npmjs" and not to "http".

Comment: I tried that solution. It didn't work for me